# I am having trouble making a program that eliminates non-alphabetical characters

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am having trouble getting my program to detect non-alphabetical characters and am stuck. Earlier I tried to use the `re.search` function, (ie re.search('[a-z]') . I currently do not understand this function and opted for code I can currently understand. If someone could explain the regex function and help me with my code it I would appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
# Eliminates characters that are not part of the alphabet from string
def eleminate_unknown(input_string):
    alpabet_list= ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

    #checks if string is upper case and makes it lower case
    if (input_string != input_string.lower()):
        print 'Upper case letters detected. Converting string to lower case.'
        input_string = input_string.lower()
    print("eleminating unknown charecters from %s") %input_string

    #creates visable division
    print '___________________________________________________________'

    for count in range(-1,(len(input_string)-1)): #need to subtract one from len of string to match index
        print input_string

        #looks for and eliminates characters not in lower case alphabet

        if (input_string[count] not in alpabet_list == False):
            print "String index %s eleminated!" %count
            print "The charecter %s died a terrable death" %input_string[count]
            print input_string[:count] + input_string[count+1:]
            input_string = input_string[:count] + input_string[count+1:]
            count = count+1
        else:
            count = count+1
            print "Index %s is not eliminated. Character %s is recognized and lives to die another day." % (count, input_string[count])
    print input_string
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/

Comment: @Owen Blail Please let me know if my answer is not clear.

Comment: If you code is working [codereview.se] may be a better place to ask. Remember to read their help center before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase

def eliminate_letters(in_string):
    for c in ascii_lowercase:
        without_lowercase = in_string.replace(c, '')
    for C in ascii_uppercase:
        no_letters = without_lowercase.replace(C, '')
    print(no_letters)
    return no_letters
```

**Explanation**: `ascii_lowercase` is a string of all the lowercase letters ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') and `ascii_uppercase` is a string of all the CAPITAL LETTERS.  The replace() function can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), as can most things you're looking for in Python.  Each character in the collection of letters gets replaced by the statements in the for loops, and then the letter-less string gets returns by the eliminate_letters() function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are complicating the process. range(n) keyword iterates until the n-1. For example range(5) iterates from 0 to 4.So it is enough to use range(len(input_string)). Moreover in your code in addition to for loop iteration, you are iterating again using count = count+1. So program skips one letter for every iteration.

```
alpabet_list=('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')

#checks if string is upper case and makes it lower case
if (input_string != input_string.lower()):
    print 'Upper case letters detected. Converting string to lower case.'
    input_string = input_string.lower()
print("eleminating unknown charecters from %s") %input_string

#creates visable division
print '___________________________________________________________'
output_string=""
for letter in input_string: 
    print input_string

    if (letter not in alphabet_list):
        print ("The character" +letter+ "died a terrable death")
    else:
        output_string = output_string+letter
    print output_string

print output_string
```